# how to run a servlet in jsp page and is it a good programming practice?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I wanted to display a table contents from my database in a jsp page. I know I have to get a list of the rows of that table in the form of objects and use the  to iterate through them.
I am trying to avoid scripting in my jsp page. So I wanted to included a servlet in my jsp page which connects to database , takes the result set of the table and add the rows as objects (of the respective class type) and add those objects to a List and set that List object as an attribute to request object.
I tried  to use <@include page="/servlet"> in the jsp page .In that servlet I connected to the database and received a result set and added the objects into a list and set attribute to request object.
It gave an error saying this servlet cannot be found.So I added <@include page="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/servlet"> . It showed no error but in that jsp page it showed an exception .How do I solve this?

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /jspPages/AdminHome.jsp at line 15

15: <jsp:include page="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/EmployeeList" />

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: The requested resource (/TestProject/TestProject/EmployeeList) is not available

Comment: when invoking one JSP page from another, you can invoke a servlet from a JSP page through the jsp:include and jsp:forward action tags, eg.

<jsp:include page="/servlet/MyServlet" flush="true" />

Comment: heyy Ashish Sharma I tried to include the servlet page in a jsp page. Its not working . I dont know where I am doing the mistake

Comment: Use beans-wrap your db functionality in a bean and have it output your list.

Comment: Please try posting your code instead of long description.

Comment: Its saying that my code is not properly formatted .  can I upload photos in here ?( This is my first time asking in this site.)

Answer (score 0):

In your JSP write code as shown below ,

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <jsp:include page="/customServlet" />
```

& In you servlet doGet method use below code to include response of servlet in jsp,

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/customServletJSP.jsp");      
    view.include(request, response);
```

RequestDispatcher interface used to forward or include response of servlet to other servlet or jsp.

Comment: Rahul Rabhadiya ,, why are you trying to include jsp page inside a servlet ?

Comment: @DRajesh I am not including jsp page inside servlet. its servlet response that is included in jsp page  , For that you have to use RequestDispatcher.

Comment: I tried to include the servlet using : <jsp: include page="/servletName"> ..It showed that servlet is not found at expected path . Then I tried to <jsp: include page="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/servletName"> . Then it showed the jasper exception in jsp page saying:
An exception occurred processing JSP page /jspPages/AdminHome.jsp at line 15 15: <jsp:include page="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/EmployeeList" />
/*servletName : EmoloyeeList;
  jspPage name: AdminHome.jsp;
*/

Comment: @DRajesh post your web.xml so We can analyse your servlet mapping for EmployeeList servlet